# What is the order of data across multiple nested fields in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

Given a BigQuery table with the schema: `target:STRING,evName:STRING,evTime:TIMESTAMP`, consider the following subselect:

```
SELECT target, 
       NEST(evName) AS evNames,
       NEST(evTime) AS evTimes,
FROM [...]
GROUP BY target
```

This will group events by target into rows with two repeated fields `evNames` and `evTimes`. I understand that the values within each of the repeated fields are not ordered in any predictable way, but is the ordering guaranteed to be consistent **between** the two repeated fields?

In other words, if I pick N-th value from evNames and N-th value from evTimes within a given row, will they form a proper pair from the original table?

What I would really like to do is to create a nested repeated record, something like:

```
SELECT target, NEST(RECORD(evName, evTime)) AS events FROM [...] GROUP BY target
```

but I believe creating RECORDs on the fly like this is currently not supported.

By the way, this question is motivated by the desire to use recently introduced BigQuery [user defined functions](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2015/08/breaking-sql-barrier-google-bigquery.html) to implement state machines, as an alternative to window functions tricks.

Note: I realize that an alternative is to emulate record by serializing multiple fields into a single string representation, e.g.:

```
SELECT target, NEST(CONCAT(evName, ',', STRING(evTime))) ...
```

and then deserialize the "record" in later stages, but I'd like to avoid that if I can.

Comment: To prove whether both NEST would be consistent would require some testing I'd say... run the query doing the two nests a couple of times and check if every row is as expected. In any case, if it's not explicitely documented, I wouldn't assume behavior either way and I'd go with the concatenation for now, until something states explicitely how the NESTing works :)